# Rails Proper Use of Unless with And Operator

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, operators

I have a Rails 3.2.18 app where I'm trying to send Twilio notifications to a medic's phone on the update action using:

```
 unless @call.call_status == "close" && @call.unit_ids.empty?
```

If a call status is set to close then that means the call is closed and no notifications need to be sent out via ActionMailer or my send_sms private method.  Also if the unit_ids is empty (array of units) no mail or sms alerts should go out either.

Here's what happens.  If The call is open and I have no units assigned (unit_ids is empty) and I update the call, it will bypass the action mailer but it still tries to fire off send_sms and raises a nilclass exception for @call.units.first.incharge since the medic/incharge does not exist in the array.  Now if I nest another unless statement within the first one (see second example working, it will not fire mailer or send_sms if the call_status == close and unit_ids.empty?

**calls_controller.rb (not working)**

```
def update
    parse_times!
    @call = Call.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.update_attributes(params[:call])
        unless (@call.call_status == "close" && @call.unit_ids.empty?)
          send_sms

        @call.send_mail(:update_call)

        end
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: "Call #{@call.incident_number} was successfully updated.".html_safe }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private
def send_sms
    account_sid = 'AACCCCCC'
    auth_token = 'ATttttt'
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
    @client.account.messages.create(
       :from => '2814084444',
       :to => @call.units.first.incharge.medic_phone,
       :body => "incident_number #{@call.incident_number} patient name #{@call.patient_name}"
      )
    @client.account.messages.create(
      :from => '2814084444',
       :to => @call.units.first.attendant.medic_phone,
       :body => "incident_number #{@call.incident_number} patient name #{@call.patient_name}"
      )
  end
end
```

**calls_controller.rb (working)**

```
def update
    parse_times!
    @call = Call.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.update_attributes(params[:call])
        unless @call.call_status == "close"
          unless  @call.unit_ids.empty?
          send_sms
        end

        @call.send_mail(:update_call)

        end
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: "Call #{@call.incident_number} was successfully updated.".html_safe }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def send_sms
    account_sid = 'ACCCCCC'
    auth_token = 'atttt'
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
    @client.account.messages.create(
       :from => '2814084444',
       :to => @call.units.first.incharge.medic_phone,
       :body => "incident_number #{@call.incident_number} patient name #{@call.patient_name}"
      )
    @client.account.messages.create(
      :from => '2814084444',
       :to => @call.units.first.attendant.medic_phone,
       :body => "incident_number #{@call.incident_number} patient name #{@call.patient_name}"
      )
  end
```

Is nesting the unless statements the proper way to do it or can I somehow combine the && operator with unless.  Maybe my syntax is wrong in the first (non working) example.  I'm obviously missing something here, so any help that is offered would be appreciated.

**Update: 08/03/14-08:03**

It seems that if I use the || operator I do not raise a nilclass exception and the mailer and send_sms fires unless the call status is close or the call unit_ids is empty.

```
 unless (@call.call_status == "close" || @call.unit_ids.empty?)
          send_sms
          @call.send_mail(:update_call)
        end
```

Does this make sense or should I try to use the && operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have correctly observed, nesting two conditionals is equivalent to combining the conditions with `&&`. Since `unless ...` is the same as `if ! ...` ("if not") you could also write:

```
if !(@call.call_status == "close") && !(@call.unit_ids.empty?)
  # ...
end
```

[De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) teaches us that `!a && !b` is the same as `!(a || b)`:

```
if !(@call.call_status == "close" || @call.unit_ids.empty?)
  # ...
end
```

Of course, we can substitute back the `if !` with an `unless`:

```
unless @call.call_status == "close" || @call.unit_ids.empty?
  # ...
end
```

Although I would rather advise you to use `if` with complex conditionals, because that is generally easier to read and understand. We start again with eliminating the `unless`:

```
if !(@call.call_status == "close") && !(@call.unit_ids.empty?)
  # ...
end
```

Then, we reformulate the parts left and right of `&&` so that the `!` is no longer necessary. In this case, we can change `==` to `!=`. We can also change `empty?` to `any?`, but that would be problematic when the array contains only `nil` and/or `false` values. If you can be sure that this never happens, you can use `x.any?` instead of `! x.empty?` as well:

```
if @call.call_status != "close" && !@call.unit_ids.empty?
  # ...
end

# If you are 100% sure that @call.unit_ids _never_ contains nil or false values,
# you can use x.any? instead of !x.empty?

if @call.call_status != "close" && @call.unit_ids.any?
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Wow, you really provided a thorough understanding and explanation of conditionals.  I thought I had a good grasp but you really provided a good "schooling" on the topic.  I tried the following: `if !(@call.call_status == "close") && !(@call.unit_ids.empty?)
          send_sms
          @call.send_mail(:update_call)
        end` and it seems to work the way I wanted unless to work and is easier to read.  So basically what you're saying is if ! works just like unless but is more legible.  I also noticed you mentioned using unless with the || operator.  I like the if statement better.

Comment: I'd also recommend adding `@call.closed?` and `@call.units_assigned?` methods to make things read better and hide away anything that messes around with `@call`'s internals.

Comment: @muistooshort good suggestion, although i'd probably rather implement a `@call.open?` method (or whatever the equivalent is for "not closed" in this specific domain).

Comment: Adding methods for closed and units_assigned is a really good idea and would definitely clean things up.

Comment: Yeah, that would work too. Or maybe even wrap both the `call_status` and `unit_ids` checks into a single "should do whatever" method or bury the `send_sms` call in with the status checks or ...